# How to generate Oracle triggers with NHibernate schema export?

Tags: nhibernate, triggers, export, ddl

Let's suppose we are developing a data layer, and we are following the "code first" principle. The database is generated from model by using SchemaExport. 
And I want to implement the following identity generating scenario:

- each table has its own sequence and trigger
- trigger is of type "for each row" and inserts next sequence value when data is inserted to the table.

This approach is supported by NHibernate by using (with fluent)

```
Id(x=>x.Id).GeneratedBy.TriggerIdentity();
```

But when I do SchemaExport to file, neither sequence, nor the trigger is generated.
How to tell NHibernate to issue DDL code for creating TRIGGER and corresponding SEQUENCE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should explicitly tell NH what additinal objects you want it to create for you.
As far as I know fluent NH doesn't allow you to configure auxiliary database objects directly. Add to your project .hbm.xml file as embedded resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
<database-object>
    <create>
        create ...
    </create>
    <drop>
        drop ...
    </drop>
</database-object>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Then tell fluent NH to pick it

```
.Mappings(m =>
{
    m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<...>();
         ... 
})
```

SchemaExport will execute your create and drop sections when exporting schema.